# Map Data from CSV file

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to pull my map data in from a csv file? see it here: http://calwestcultural.com/sgs/example_map.html

Comment: Add more details... Which language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: i posted the link above with my map example. I am using standard HTML but would prefer a PHP solution or something simple I can integrate with my HTML/Javascript document.